# How to use the MAX and Case function over three tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have joined three tables using Max and Case functions.

When I used two tables it working fine but when I added the third table I got this error.

**Ambiguous column name 'Month'.**

```
SELECT  Category ,
        KPI ,
        TDTargetValue ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Jan' THEN Input
            END) Jan ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Feb' THEN Input
            END) Feb ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Mar' THEN Input
            END) Mar ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Apr' THEN Input
            END) Apr ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'May' THEN Input
            END) May ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Jun' THEN Input
            END) Jun ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Jul' THEN Input
            END) Jul ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Aug' THEN Input
            END) Aug ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Sep' THEN Input
            END) Sep ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Oct' THEN Input
            END) Oct ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Nov' THEN Input
            END) Nov ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Month = 'Dec' THEN Input
            END) Dec
FROM    [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[NewCriteria] NC
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT *
                     FROM   [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[UpdateData]
                     WHERE  PeriodId = '1'
                   ) UD ON UD.Cid = NC.Id
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[TargetData]
                  ) TD ON UD.Cid = TD.CId
WHERE   NC.Grade = 'A'
        AND IsActived = '0'
GROUP BY Category ,
        KPI ,
        TDTargetValue
ORDER BY 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Error message says that `Month` column is present in **more than one table** present in `JOIN` so please use **Alias name** to qualify the column

Comment: Thank you. i will figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `alias` also for the column Month...

Assuming `NewCriteria` table has the column `Month`

```
SELECT  Category ,
        KPI ,
        TDTargetValue ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Jan' THEN Input
            END) Jan ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Feb' THEN Input
            END) Feb ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Mar' THEN Input
            END) Mar ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Apr' THEN Input
            END) Apr ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'May' THEN Input
            END) May ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Jun' THEN Input
            END) Jun ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Jul' THEN Input
            END) Jul ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Aug' THEN Input
            END) Aug ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Sep' THEN Input
            END) Sep ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Oct' THEN Input
            END) Oct ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Nov' THEN Input
            END) Nov ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN NC.Month = 'Dec' THEN Input
            END) Dec
FROM    [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[NewCriteria] NC
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT *
                     FROM   [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[UpdateData]
                     WHERE  PeriodId = '1'
                   ) UD ON UD.Cid = NC.Id
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[TargetData]
                  ) TD ON UD.Cid = TD.CId
WHERE   NC.Grade = 'A'
        AND IsActived = '0'
GROUP BY Category ,
        KPI ,
        TDTargetValue
ORDER BY 1
```